# How to define a class when not all members available

Tags: oop

I have a class `X` with some member variables except the database ID,
an object of `X` will be processed by some function and returned along with the ID

The question is what's the best data representation in this case?
I have the following options in mind

Option A:
define `Class X` and `Class XwithID` and convert `X` to `XwithID` when ID is available

Option B: 
define `Class X` and return pair< ID , X >

Option C:
define `Class X` with the ID inside and throw exception if ID accessed before it is being assigned a value.

what are better options or best practice in this case?

Comment: no enough info, depends highly on `X` instances usage between their creation and when their `ID` becomes available

Answer (score 0):

Another option could be: have the ID  property readonly, the class not creatable ( ie private or protected constructor ) and some sort of factory inside it:`x.CreateOne()` that assign the ID.

Comment: but you need the structure without the ID, the ID will come as a result of the parameters already existing inside X

Comment: If you use some factory pattern/builder pattern, the object will be usable just when all properties are intialized, thus the ID as well.